# Как перейти на другую страницу с выполнение функцией?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я работаю в Sublime Text, и у меня 2 страницы (Home и Products), на второй страницы есть функций (например function electro(){[код]}), сне надо чтобы при переходе на второй страницы с выполнение этой функций, вызов функций должен быть сделан из первый страницы.

Comment: Распишите, пожалуйста подробнее, потому что ничего не понятно. При каком переходе? Откуда мы переходим? Куда переходим? Переходим из Home на Products и сразу после перехода выполняется функция electro?

Comment: да, при переходе из Home в Products, через ссылку должна выполнятся функция electro которая находится на странице Products

Comment: Добавьте в Products,  к вашему body параметр onload например вот так: <body onload="electro()">

Comment: Это не то, мне надо иммено чтобы ссылка запустила функцию. У меня в Home есть горячие категорий а в Products есть несколько функций которые сортируют только нужный, при переходе мне надо задействовать одну из этих функций, каждая ссылка должно начать свою функцию.

Comment: Ок, передавайте в Product из Home, Get параметры. На Proguct на onload повесьте функцию, которая будет анализировать входящие параметры и в зависимости от них - запускать функцию electro или любую другую.